# Split a string and get the second last word

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string "Hai,Hello,How,are,you"

What I needed is I need the second last word that is "are"

```
String string = "Hai,Hello,How,are,you";

String[] bits = string.split(",");
String lastWord = bits[bits.length-1]
tvs.setText(lastWord);
```

But when I did like this:

```
String lastWord = bits[bits.length-2];
```

I am not getting the second last word.

Comment: Character or word?

Comment: Array starts from 0th index. word you want is at bits.length-2 location

Comment: I gave like that... but I didnt got..

Comment: I just tried it. Jeet's answer worked well for me.

Comment: Share the output which you getting with your current code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is `String lastWord = bits[bits.length-2];` because `bits[bits.length-1];` will return you the last word and not the second last.

This is because indexing of array starts with `0` and ends in `length-1`.

Here is the updated code snippet:

```
String string = "Hai,Hello,How,are,you";
String[] bits = string.split(",");
String lastWord = bits[bits.length - 2];
tvs.setText(lastWord);
```

Comment: I gave like that.. But I didnt got the result

Comment: @Jocheved then you have a different problem. This answer is correct.

Comment: thanks... the problem was with me... actually the second last character was a null character. so it didnt returned anyhting.. now it is working fine.. thanks..

Comment: @Jocheved Your Welcome! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here first you have to find out index of  character ',' from last.
And after that second character ',' from the last. 
After that you can find out sub string between them .

```
String string = "Hai,Hello,How,are,you";
        int lastIndex,secondLastIndex;
        lastIndex=string.lastIndexOf(',');
        secondLastIndex=string.lastIndexOf(',',lastIndex-1);
        System.out.println(string.substring(secondLastIndex+1,lastIndex));
```

try it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think like this.

if your code is as follows, it does not work.

```
String string = "Hai,Hello,How,are,";
String[] bits = string.split(",");
　↓
bits[]…{ "Hai","Hello","How","are" }
bits[bits.length-2]…"How"
```

This code works.

```
String string = "Hai,Hello,How,are,";
String[] bits = string.split(",", -1);
　↓
bits[]…{ "Hai","Hello","How","are","" }
bits[bits.length-2]…"are"
```